# Ubuntu froze then when restarting failed to load

Tags: filesystem, root, fsck

I took pic but too large to send. I’ll try to downscale later. This is what it said:

```
Running/Scripts/local-premonition.... done
Will now check root file systems .... fsck from util-Linux 2.31.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) - - /dev/sda5j fsck.ext4 -a -CO /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes  that were part of a corrupt orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY;Run MANUALLY
     (i.e. , without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
done
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck
```

I got that by running advanced recover options or whatever instead of general load Ubuntu. I have files on there I cannot lose and cannot even access through special software through my windows partition. I cannot just reinstall Ubuntu and lose those files. Please help ASAP. I have clients from my business with files on there. Never had this problem before

Comment: **DANGER DANGER** re: "*and cannot even access through special software through my windows partition*"... if you've installed a Windows driver that allows you to read/write to ext2/3/4 partitions... uninstall it ASAP. That's what may have caused your problem.

Comment: status please...

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

## Then backup your important data!

Answer (score -1):

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as you reboot, and select `Advanced options`, boot into single user mode ("Root shell"). Then,

```
fsck /dev/sda5
```

This may not repair the disk, or it may. See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/fsck.8.html

Consider Backup when your system is working again.

Comment: This won't work on Ubuntu 18.04 or newer, as the disk is mounted r/w, and has active processes open on it.